# What are the advantages of selfdestruct-ing a smart contract?

Tags: contract-design, selfdestruct

I know this might be a subjective question but I am trying to understand why the ability to selfdistract a contract exists. What is the use of self distract? Are there any dapps using self distract as a feature?

Comment: https://blog.b9lab.com/selfdestruct-is-a-bug-9c312d1bb2a5 read this article. There are some Dapps use this feature to save gas fees because when u free memory in the blockchain you get gas back -> take a look at the gas token of 1inch , however getting refund will be disabled in the next ethereum update

Comment: I now understand on of the reasons why that functionality exists. It os to be able to de-congest the blockchain. Thanks. Let me read the article. If I have any follow up questions I just ask.

Comment: Just read the article. It was really informing